# How in Joomla CMS catch a event of control

Tags: javascript, api, joomla, content-management-system

I need to catch for example a button click in joomla cms, because after this there should be another procedure which is I need to code myself (fetching data from db and sending for approval to another website, i'm doing this with API of those website), and only after this procedure finish, joomla should continue it's work.
How to achieve this? Do I need to use API of Joomla CMS or some javascript library, e.g. ajax?

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You descritpion is a little vague. You most likely want to create a plugin. Plugins use Joomla Events (which means a php event mechanism) so that you can hook your code before or after most commonly happening actions in the Joomla Codebase. If you specifically need to catch a button click you want your plugin to render some javascript code. In Joomla 3.9 that typically uses jQuery. That Javascript then of course should use Ajax to reach your php code that gets DB and remote stuff. Ajax in Joomla is a wholy new book, though.

In short, I would recomment looking up how to develop plugins and how to deply Ajax in Joomla, from there you can figure out a way.